# How can I convert videos for my Sansa Fuze?

Tags: video, mp3-player

The [Sansa Fuze](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sansa_Fuze) mp3 player can only play videos in its own special format, how can I convert videos to this format using Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Video4Fuze](http://code.google.com/p/video4fuze/) application.

Comment: For historical linkage, we should look at getting the necessary source packages from http://code.google.com/p/video4fuze/downloads/list into Debian so that they can be included in Ubuntu.